# Dataset for reapeated measures

Tags: data-request, data.gov

I need data sets to apply a study based on repeated measures. I need of hints to find open data of nature that be possible to publish in scientific journals.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. Can you be more specific?  Otherwise, the community isn't sure how to be helpful.